# OpenFaas Autoscaling from 0

Tags: autoscaling, openfaas

I am trying out OpenFaas auto scaling feature from 0 instances.
I tried running nodeinfo function with this and tried invoking it.
kubectl scale deployment --replicas=0 nodeinfo -n openfaas-fn
Once replicas are down to 0, I wanted to try invoking it from Gateway UI to make it auto scale from 0, but status is not ready and Invoke button is inactive until I bump up replica count to more than 0. It seems like it is not possible to invoke a function that has 0 instances.

It doesn't look like auto scaling from 0 working, unless I am missing something.
Any guidance or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the first function invocation with the command line.

**Example:**

`echo -n "google.com" | faas-cli invoke curl --gateway 127.0.0.1:31112`

Here, `curl` is the function's name

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: echo -n "http://www.google.com" | faas-cli invoke curl --gateway http://127.0.0.1:31112 here 'curl' is the function's name